# Facebook Graph API: Create/Update Event Picture not working

Tags: facebook, api, events, image

I want to update an event's picture as described in the [Event API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/).

```
$eventId = '291145580981541';
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken(); // have tested, is correct
$data = array('source' => '@'.realpath($file));

try {
    $result = $facebook->api('/$eventId/picture?access_token=$accessToken', 'POST', $data);
    echo $result;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: $e";
}
```

The result I get:

```
Exception: OAuthException: (#200)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Variable names are not parsed inside single quotes in PHP. Use `"` or `'/'.$eventId.'/picture?access_token='.$accessToken` instead. And please read up on this very basic piece of PHP knowledge you are missing: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Actually the URL is hardcoded in my script without variables. I just wrote it here with variables for better clearness. So imagine the single quotes are double quotes, I'm sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Error `#200` is a permissions error. You most likely don't have the `create_event` permission

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#picture

Comment: I do have the permission. I can create an event through the API without error (tested several times), I just can't update the event picture.

Comment: @user1545860 print the error to error_log or use $e->getMessage(); because that's the only way to be sure.

Comment: $e->getMessage() just returns "(#200)".

Comment: @user1545860 dump the error object then, because that's not the whole response. There is a message that comes with it

Comment: [result:protected] => Array
            (
                [error] => Array
                    (
                        [message] => (#200) 
                        [type] => OAuthException
                        [code] => 200
                    )
    
            )
    
        [message:protected] => (#200) 
        [string:Exception:private] => 
        [code:protected] => 0
        [file:protected] => /[...]/base_facebook.php
        [line:protected] => 1238
        [trace:Exception:private] => Array (...)

Comment: my permissions:                     [installed] => 1
                    [status_update] => 1
                    [photo_upload] => 1
                    [video_upload] => 1
                    [create_event] => 1
                    [create_note] => 1
                    [share_item] => 1
                    [publish_stream] => 1
                    [manage_pages] => 1
                    [publish_actions] => 1

Comment: @user1545860 submit a bug, I'm out of options to what's causing this